# How to find original sender of email?

Tags: postfix

I found some messages that were to be delievered to rpub@domain.tld and would like to know who sent them. When searching the logs I find the sender is "<>" so it might be postfix (mailer daemon), but how can I trace back the original sender ?

```
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/cleanup[610]: 6766E1E922DB: message-id=<20160918133402.6766E1E922DB@messagerie.domain.tld>
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 6766E1E922DB: from=<>, size=35673, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 18 14:34:03 messagerie postfix/pipe[648]: 6766E1E922DB: to=<rpub@domain.tld>, relay=maildrop, delay=0.59, delays=0.03/0.19/0/0.37, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: /usr/bin/maildrop: Unable to create a dot-lock at /var/vmail/domain.tld/rpub/1116.0.messagerie.domain.tld.  )
Sep 18 14:41:30 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 6766E1E922DB: from=<>, size=35673, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 18 14:41:30 messagerie postfix/pipe[656]: 6766E1E922DB: to=<rpub@domain.tld>, relay=maildrop, delay=448, delays=448/0.07/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: /usr/bin/maildrop: Unable to create a dot-lock at /var/vmail/domain.tld/rpub/4281.0.messagerie.domain.tld.  )
Sep 18 14:51:30 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 6766E1E922DB: from=<>, size=35673, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 18 14:51:31 messagerie postfix/pipe[5595]: 6766E1E922DB: to=<rpub@domain.tld>, relay=maildrop, delay=1049, delays=1049/0.11/0/0.04, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: /usr/bin/maildrop: Unable to create a dot-lock at /var/vmail/domain.tld/rpub/5601.0.messagerie.domain.tld.  )
Sep 18 15:11:30 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 6766E1E922DB: from=<>, size=35673, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 18 15:11:30 messagerie postfix/pipe[8843]: 6766E1E922DB: to=<rpub@domain.tld>, relay=maildrop, delay=2248, delays=2248/0.11/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: /usr/bin/maildrop: Unable to create a dot-lock at /var/vmail/domain.tld/rpub/9050.0.messagerie.domain.tld.  )
```

---

## Edit

As pointed out by @RyanBabchishin I have skipped some lines in the logs. By searching carefully again for the qid I found this :

```
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/cleanup[610]: 6766E1E922DB: message-id=<20160918133402.6766E1E922DB@messagerie.algerian-radio.dz>
[... Many lines later ...]
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/bounce[777]: 283821E922D9: sender non-delivery notification: 6766E1E922DB
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 6766E1E922DB: from=<>, size=35673, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

So in reality 6766E1E922DB is a bounce of 283821E922D9. If I search for 283821E922D9 I can get to the original sender (which should be rpub itself) :

```
Sep 18 14:34:01 messagerie postfix/smtpd[31851]: 283821E922D9: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 18 14:34:01 messagerie postfix/cleanup[718]: 283821E922D9: message-id=<6045b91e32d9f289230c7a550015256d@algerian-radio.dz>
Sep 18 14:34:01 messagerie postfix/smtpd[31851]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 18 14:34:01 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 283821E922D9: from=<rpub@algerian-radio.dz>, size=32590, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
```

Quod Erat Demonstrandum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching the logs again

```
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/cleanup[610]: 6766E1E922DB: message-id=<20160918133402.6766E1E922DB@messagerie.algerian-radio.dz>
[... Many lines later ...]
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/bounce[777]: 283821E922D9: sender non-delivery notification: 6766E1E922DB
Sep 18 14:34:02 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 6766E1E922DB: from=<>, size=35673, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Is was a bounce for 283821E922D9. A search for that QID gives the original sender :

```
Sep 18 14:34:01 messagerie postfix/qmgr[2749]: 283821E922D9: from=<rpub@algerian-radio.dz>, size=32590, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
```

Answer (score 1):

A sender of an e-mail can easily be spoofed, so you can't use the senders e-mail for anything useful. The only relevant information you can trust is the SMTP-server from which the e-mail was sent.

Comment: I'd rather have that info than no info at all.

Comment: @ychaouche Your logs are missing info. You should be seeing stuff like `postfix/smtpd[14775]: connect from host.example.com[192.168.1.125]`. Look into increasing log verbosity (unless you just left it out).

Comment: Thanks indeed I was leaving out a lot of lines from the logs. By looking at it again I eventually found out it was a bounce.